# Is a reasonable spacetime geodesically connected?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, topology, geodesics

There are some theorems concerning whether a spacetime is geodesically connected (whether any two points $p, q \in M$ admit a geodesic connecting them) or not, ie [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005039)[[2]](https://www.esi.ac.at/static/esiprpr/esi1850.pdf), but all of these are concerned with either rather simplistic spacetimes, which would not really apply to our own universe, or have very specific conditions that seem perhaps too narrow.

Is there a theorem that our own universe would be geodesically connected? Throwing around a few "reasonable" conditions, that may imply spacetimes with the following properties:

- Globally hyperbolic
- Maximally extended
- Obeying some reasonable energy condition (ie the null energy condition or the generic condition)
- Bounded stress-energy tensor

It can be shown rather easily that this is false just admitting global hyperbolicity and the NEC (ie. the spacetime constructed by taking the union of two future light cone in Minkowski space), or by taking a Weyl transform of this spacetime so that the Riemann tensor diverges on its boundary, so that it is also maximally extended.

Is there a specific theorem for a plausible spacetime where it is geodesically connected, or is that simply wrong, or unknown?

Comment: IIRC even simple pp-wave type spacetimes are generally *not* geodesically connected. So the answer to a title question is probably “no”. *I'll try to dig up link and write an answer later*.

Comment: @A.V.S. That is some of the reasons I would not consider PP-wave space-times generally physically plausible. The point is that since the wave is infinitely extended, in a (not-rigorously-defined) sense of the word, they carry infinite energy.

Comment: @Void: It is not the infinite dimensions but the focusing properties that are behind this geodesic disconnectedness: all geodesics emanating from some points are focused and the “shadow” regions thus have no geodesics from that point. If we limit dimensions of the “lens” and even introduce small enough perturbations, shadows would still persist.

Comment: @A.V.S. Well, I would still like to see a source that produces a wave strong enough for a lens. Binary inspirals have a maximum luminosity at equal masses and coalescence. This is associated with a time scale and a length scale. I.e., you will have a limit on the size of the region where the pp-approximation to a real wave will become bad (you need to include curvature of the wavefront and modulation).

Comment: @Void Even weak wave could produce lensing, you just have to increase the distance (both focal points).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether a “reasonable” spacetime is geodesically connected depends on the definition of “reasonable”.

If we consider *globally hyperbolic* spacetime as reasonable, then there is a theorem by Avez (1963) & Seifert (1967), that states that globally hyperbolic spacetimes are *causally* geodesically connected. Note, that the two points here must be causally connected, the theorem says nothing about points that are not causally related. For a proof of the theorem, as well as other sufficient conditions in terms of disprisonment and pseudoconvexity see the book:

- Beem J.K., Ehrlich P.E., Easley K.L. (1996) *Global Lorentzian geometry*. Marcel Dekker, New York.

or a more recent (and open access) review:

- Minguzzi, E. (2019). *Lorentzian causality theory*. Living reviews in relativity, 22(1), 3, [doi:10.1007/s41114-019-0019-x](https://doi.org/10.1007/s41114-019-0019-x).

Universal covering of **anti-de Sitter** is an example of spacetime that is not geodesically connected: all timelike geodesics that are emanating from a given point $p$ are focused in an *antipodal* point $q$, so a point $r$, with a spacelike separation from $q$ has *no* geodesics connecting it to $p$ despite being causally connected to it (see figure):

[image: timelike geodesics in AdS]

While arguably anti-de Sitter is not a *reasonable* spacetime, since it corresponds to negative cosmological constant, there is *Bertotti–Robinson solution* of Einstein–Maxwell system which is just $\text{AdS}_2 \times S_2$ and so it is maximally extended, with a bounded stress–energy tensor obeying reasonable energy conditions, yet not geodesically connected.

Another interesting group of spacetimes without geodesic connectedness consists of various pp-wave solutions. As first noticed for both purely gravitational and EM+gravitational *plane waves* (a subclass of pp-waves with a higher symmetry) by [R. Penrose in 1965](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.37.215),  focusing behavior of null geodesics from a specifically chosen points precludes such spacetimes from being globally hyperbolic and geodesically connected. Various generalizations of such spacetimes has been considered see e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0211017) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0410006). Imposition of “reasonable” constraints on such spacetimes such as finiteness or asymptotic flatness of the front often results in global hyperbolicity and geodesic connectedness.

So, overall, conditions for geodesic connectedness of spacetime must be *global* in character (so just some specific energy condition would not do).

Comment: There are globally hyperbolic spacetimes which are not geodesically connected (even if they are causally geodesically connected): remove $J^-(p)$ from Minkowski spacetime. The remaining space is globally hyperbolic, but not geodesically connected. I see that this example is artificial, but it shows that glob hyperboliticity  does not imply geodesic connectedness.

Comment: Also in a g.h. spacetime there is exactly a unique geodesic with maximal length joining two causally related points. I think the most up-to-date reference is the one by Minguzzi.